# Bootstrap data table after click on print button application not responding

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

I'm using [Data tables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html), As requirement I was implemented the print functionality I initialized the bootstrap data table with following code.

```
  var dataTableObj = {
    "scrollX": true,
    "destroy": true,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "FirstName"
      }, {
        "data": "CollegeName"
      }, {
        "data": "Gender"
      }, {
        "data": "Qualification"
      }, {
        "data": "Branch"
      }, {
        "data": "EmailID"
      }, {
        "data": "Phone"
      },
      /*{
          "className": "downloadOfferletter",
          "data": "OfferLetter",
          "bSortable": false
      }*/
    ],
    dom: '<l>Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'excel',
        title: 'Students'
      },

      {
        extend: 'pdf',
        title: 'Students'
      }, {
        extend: 'print',
        title: 'Students'
      },

    ],
    fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
      $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a href="#students/add/' + aData['StudentID'] + '">' +
        aData['FirstName'] + '</a>');

      return nRow;
    },
  };
```

Here the problem is when I click on print button it will open a new tab it was showing the print window, this is fine.

When I come back to my application[Previous opened browser tab] without closing the print window[tab] the application is not responding.

Can anyone please give suggestion to fix this, If we can't fix this Is there any possibility to open the print window in the same window which is my application window.

Comment: Sounds like a browser problem, what are you using? Try set `autoPrint: false `...

Comment: Then Application behaves likes this  https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/autoPrint.html.

Comment: I don't want that, I need to show print window also

Comment: Please need help :-(

Comment: I am too facing the same issue, is there any solutions?